# How to pass DocuSign email EmailBlurb for each signer?

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

I have create envelope and pass signer,document, position to sign.So in that i need to pass EmailBlurb for each signer separately.Form Docusing web ui can set using following option and each signer get different message.
[image]

So how to pass this message from Docusing code, here the piece of code which i pass 2 signers

```
Private Function MakeEnvelope(ByVal signerEmail As String, ByVal signerName As String) As EnvelopeDefinition
Dim buffer As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Config.docPdf)
Dim envelopeDefinition As EnvelopeDefinition = New EnvelopeDefinition()
envelopeDefinition.EmailSubject = "Please sign this document"
envelopeDefinition.EmailBlurb ="Dear. A Thanks and regards"  ' this will appear for both signer
Dim doc1 As Document = New Document()
Dim doc1b64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
doc1.DocumentBase64 = doc1b64
doc1.Name = "Lorem Ipsum"
doc1.FileExtension = "pdf"
doc1.DocumentId = "1"

envelopeDefinition.Documents = New List(Of Document) From {
    doc1
}
Dim signer1 As Signer = New Signer With {
    .Email = signerEmail,
    .Name = signerName,
    .ClientUserId = signerClientId,
    .RecipientId = "1"
}
Dim signer2 As Signer = New Signer With {
    .Email = signerEmail2,
    .Name = signerName2,
    .ClientUserId = signerClientId2,
    .RecipientId = "2"
}
```

This will appear for both signer as same message, i need to make each signer name need to show there.

```
envelopeDefinition.EmailBlurb ="Dear. A Thanks and regards"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-blog-series-common-api-tasks-change-email-subject-and-body-for-each-recipient) shows how to do that in six langs, including C#. I have converted the C# to VB.NET for you and here it is:

```
Dim signer1 As Signer = New Signer With {
    .Email = "inbar@example.com",
    .Name = "Inbar Gazit",
    .RecipientId = "1",
    .RoutingOrder = "1",
    .EmailNotification = New RecipientEmailNotification With {
        .EmailSubject = "Custom email subject for signer 1",
        .EmailBody = "Custom email body for signer 1"
    }
}Z
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works and i finish Docsuing project  fully with your help in production account.

Comment: @AravindAravind if you want to send me an email - inbar.gazit@docusign.com - would love to hear about your project.